# Error when running binary with root setuid under encrypted home directory

Tags: 12.10, ecryptfs, vpnc

I'm using a VPN script for Juniper's Secure Access protocol form [here](http://mad-scientist.us/juniper.html), which executes a binary located under `~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc` with the following permissions:

```
-rws--s--x 1 root root 1225424 okt.  25 13:54 ncsvc
```

But when I do, I get the following error:

```
ncsvc> Failed to setuid to root. Error 1: Operation not permitted
```

Moving/copying the `~/.juniper_networks` folder to e.g. `/opt/juniper` (with the same owner permissions), I don't get the error. In the forum thread at [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=232607&page=51) someone pointed out that it's probably because I have encrypted my `/home` and thus a "problem" with ecryptfs.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The nosuid mount option is used when the eCryptfs mount is set up. This is done for security reasons to prevent privilege escalation attacks.

You can move the ncsvc binary outside of your home directory (just like you did with /opt/juniper/) and create a symlink from your ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc to the new location.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to make eCryptfs set `suid` instead of `nosuid`? The eCryptfs options does not appear in the /etc/fstab file.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: But why? The same script worked in 12.04, so this change has to be recent.

Comment: Because of security concerns. An unprivileged user could mount a user-created (possibly malicious) filesystem on a USB drive. The mount would be marked nosuid. But then the unprivileged user could mount eCryptfs on top of it and execute setuid-root binaries. This vulnerability was assigned CVE-2012-3409 and was fixed in ecryptfs-utils-99.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two work around for the encrypted /home partition.

1. If you connect to a VPN via a website, start firefox with: `sudo firefox` since it is likely your /root is not encrypted. After network connect starts you can close the browser and leave the client running in the background.
2. This is from what was mentioned before. Basically have the client running outside of an encrypted partition:

   ```
   rm ~/.juniper_networks
   sudo mkdir /opt/.juniper_networks
   ln -s /opt/.juniper_networks ~/.juniper_networks
   sudo chown yourusername:yourgroupname /opt/.juniper_networks
   ```

After the above start and proceed with installing network connect again. This time it will be installed in `/opt/.juniper_networks`.