# "Failed to setuid to root." How do I Establish a VPN network?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, networking, permissions, vpn

My university decided that the old VPN-network, which worked fine, wasn't good enough anymore and abandoned it. Now I have to establish a completely new VPN-network. My university provided me with a manual (in dutch) which I followed, but it doesn't work. Almost everything could be the problem but where I'm really stuck is at the part where terminal says:

```
open(/home/simon/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc.log) failed: Permission denied
ncsvc> Failed to setuid to root. Error 1: Operation not permitted
```

This happens everytime I enter the command that my university told me to execute:

```
'/usr/local/nc/ncsvc' ./ncsvc -h uvavpn.uva.nl -u < username > -r users -f uvavpn.uva.nl.der
```

I searched some fora looking for anwsers but since I'm a new Ubuntu user I didn't understand what was going on at all. Is there someone out there who knows how to solve this error? And can explain it to me in the easiest possible way?
I use Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit.

I do hope that this is the right place to ask this question,
Thanks in advance, Simon

Answer (score 4):

It's mostly a problem of your HOME-directory. It's encrypted, am I right? ;)
So it is mounted with a "nosetuid" option, that prevents any SUID Operations to work as you expect them.

Solution: copy your `network-connect` directory somewhere else on your HDD i.e. `/opt/juniperconnect`, edit the `junipernc-script` to point to the new directory (called `_jpath` in the script `/usr/local/bin/junipernc` ), and then it works for me. I'm still using nc version 7.1 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: One addition I would make is to copy the network_connect dir and then make a symlink for ncsvc.  Otherwise it can't be found when launching it from Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

If your home directory is encrypted, then this is a duplicate of [Error when running binary with root setuid under encrypted home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210048/error-when-running-binary-with-root-setuid-under-encrypted-home-directory).  If it's not (or your entire drive is encrypted, which is different), then you can fix this like this:

```
$ ll ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc
-rwx--x--x 1 mvorburger mvorburger 1274492 Feb 14 14:14 ncsvc
$ sudo chown root:root ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc
$ sudo chmod 6711 ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc
$ ll ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc
-rws--s--x 1 root root 1274492 Feb 14 14:14 ncsvc
```

Comment: Pulse version 8.1R8 had this exact problem after my install.  Perhaps because I used Alien to install it, but I had to manually untar pulsesvc out of a pulse.tgz, and it had bad permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the UvA VPN? This took me a long time to solve as well. Here are some questions to see how far your installation has progressed:

Have you downloaded the certificate into the /user/local/nc folder?

Have you installed Java?

And, don't forget to change your directory to the /user/local/nc folder before executing the command as well.

For me, the command I have put into a little script runs as follows:

cd /usr/local/nc

sudo ./ncsvc -h uvavpn.uva.nl -u  -r users -f uvavpn.uva.nl.der

(don't forget to replace  with your username).

Let me know if this helps you along, if not, I can check what's wrong from there.